# Transmission daemon start a program once download is over

Tags: linux, ubuntu, transmission

Is there a documentation somewhere for the transmission daemon so that I can start a program once the download is over ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `-f, -finish script` you can specify script to run when the torrent finishes. 
[Manual](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/transmissioncli/#DESCRIPTION_687h) and [examples](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Scripts#OnTorrentCompletion)